# Vibrate not working with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an AlarmActivity in my app, and within it I want to be able check the value for the key "vibrate" in my preferences.xml file and then start the vibrate pattern in my AlarmActivity if the key returns true. I thought I was on-track with this, but apparently I'm not.

AlarmActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);

    final Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.j5tech.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean alarmVibrate = prefs.getBoolean("vibrate", false);
    if (alarmVibrate){

        long[] pattern = { 0, 200, 500 };
        vib.vibrate(pattern, 0);

    }else{

    }
...
}
```

In my preferences.xml...

```
<PreferenceScreen  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="vibrate"
    android:title="@string/vibrate_setting_title"
    android:summary="@string/vibrate_setting_summary"
    android:defaultValue="false" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: is this all of your code or have you written something else?
where is the part that toggles your variable alarmVibrate and sets it to true?

Comment: Apparently I am more confused by all of this than I originally thought I was. I thought that toggling the CheckBoxPreference in the UI set the boolean value. Then the value of that key is called in my AlarmActivity with `boolean alarmVibrate = prefs.getBoolean("vibrate", false);` Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: there is nothing in your code that links toggling the boolean value alarmVibrate to true or false on changing the state of the checkbox.
i can't give you the model answer here because you will not learn , by the way a SharedPreferences is one of simple storage options in android to store simple values such as strings or integers, but CheckBoxPreference is something in the UI.

Comment: can you tell me exactly what you want to do so maybe i can guide you to some tutorials

Comment: I'm just trying to get vibrate to work conditionally, based on the value of the CheckBoxPreference in my preferences.xml. I am assuming I am missing something from PreferencesActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew I wasn't smokin' crack over here. With SharedPreferences, I shouldn't have to go through a whole bunch of this and set that. It's taken care of by the class. Below is what I ended up doing to get my settings to properly work with the vibrate method in my AlarmActivity.

There is the UI object, a CheckBoxPreference, in preferences.xml:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:name="@+id/chkbxVibrate"
    android:key="vibrate"
    android:title="@string/vibrate_setting_title"
    android:summary="@string/vibrate_setting_summary"
    android:defaultValue="false" />
```

Then the PreferencesActivity.java is pretty simple:

```
...
public class PreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

}
...
}
```

Then in my AlarmActivity, where I wanted to check on the value of the CheckBoxPreference object:

```
final Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    long[] pattern = { 0, 200, 500 };

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean vibrate = prefs.getBoolean("vibrate", true);
    if (vibrate == true){

        vib.vibrate(pattern, 0);
    }
```

It was as easy as that! I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

set the vibrate permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: That's not the problem. I can get vibrate to work, just not conditionally, based on the CheckBoxPreference in my preferences.xml

Comment: oh, I see, but you are reading the sharedpreferences from the file com.j5tech.app. Are you saving the preferences from the PreferenceActivity in that file? You have to call PreferenceManager prefMgr = getPreferenceManager();
        prefMgr.setSharedPreferencesName("com.j5tech.app");

Comment: to clarify: PreferenceActivity will save your preferences in the "default" file, which internally will be saved something like com.j5tech.app_preferences.xml. But you are reading specifically from a file called "com.j5tech.app", which doesn't have your changes. Either you make the PreferenceActivity write to the other file or you read the default preferences in your AlarmActivity like this: SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());